# References for the early history of Fontaine's tilting construction

Tags: reference-request, arithmetic-geometry, p-adic-hodge-theory

Scholze attributes the tilting construction for perfectoid rings to Fontaine, who calls it "a classical construction in $p$-adic Hodge theory".

Would anyone happen to know an early reference where one can see this construction being used to good effect? Are there canonical examples of classic applications?

Comment: I suggest that you read Fontaine's Bourbaki seminar on perfectoid spaces.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jean-Marc Fontaine *Groupes p-divisibles sur les corps locaux.* Astérisque 47-48, Soc. Math. France, Paris (1977), i+262 pp (especially chapter V)

This is probably the canonical answer to your question. Note that the application was found before *tilting* was defined, even for fields, as is usually the case in the history of mathematics.

Jean-Marc Fontaine and Jean-Pierre Wintenberger. *Le "corps des normes'' de certaines extensions algébriques de corps locaux, C. R. Acad. Sci. Paris Sér. A-B 288 (1979), 367-370

Jean-Marc Fontaine and Jean-Pierre Wintenberger. *Extensions algébrique et corps des normes des extensions APF des corps locaux.* C. R. Acad. Sci. Paris Sér. A-B, 288(8) :A441–A444, 1979.

Jean-Pierre Wintenberger. *Le corps des normes de certaines extensions infinies de corps locaux ; applications.* Ann. Sci. École Norm. Sup. (4), 16(1) :59–89, 1983.

Two mathematicians that are sorely missed.

For a more recent application (still much older than perfectoids), see for instance

Christophe Breuil *Une application du corps des normes.* Compositio Math. 117, 1999, 189-203